# Can we show library content in customer community?

Tags: community

I want to show some documents in the content library to customer community users. Can this be done?

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_content.htm&language=en_US

> Update Customer Portal profiles:
>
> Clone the Customer Portal User or Customer Portal Manager profile.
>
> In the cloned profiles, add the “View Content in Portals” user permission.
>
> Change the tab visibility for the Libraries, Content, and Subscriptions tabs from Tab Hidden to Default On.
>
> Assign the cloned profiles to your Customer Portal users.

I cant find `View Content in Portals` for the foll licenses

```
Authenticated Website
High Volume Customer Portal
Customer Portal Managed Custom
Customer Portal Managed Standard
```

Is there some way we could enable content for these licenses?

EDIT:
Do these licenses also dont have access to content?

```
 Customer Community
 Customer Community Login
 High volume Customer Login
```

EDIT :
Looking at this post http://limitexception.herod.net/2013/08/28/salesforce-object-type-by-community-or-portal-type/

Content is not available for customer communities licenses and only available for partner communities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

High volume licenses (Authenticated Website and High Volume Customer Portal profiles) don't support access to content.

Customer Portal Manager Standard/Custom profiles can, but you can't set this permission on the standard profiles (even the one that is named Custom!).  Rather you need to clone them to create a custom profile and then this checkbox will appear.  We are using this for our customer portal and haven't had any problems.

If you aren't seeing the checkbox on the profiles I'd contact Salesforce support - I have an old developer org which also doesn't have the checkboxes, as it was provisioned when content was a feature license.  Although I now have content, as part of it being included with full Salesforce licenses, it didn't seem to propagate through everywhere it should have.

Comment: Do these Customer Community,
Customer Community Login,
High volume Customer Login also dont have access to content?

Comment: Customer community only supports high volume licenses, so they won't have access to content.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is now added to the new Customer Community + license type